# Does console.log() get sent to the call stack

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout, console.log

I am trying to understand event loops and callback queues better. I think one thing that would help is knowing if console.log() goes to the call stack and gets treated the same way as an invoked function, or if it takes another path to the console

Comment: This varies by implementation; it's not a standard. However, `console.log()` is, externally, a simple function call. What happens *inside* the `console` implementation is up to the runtime.

Comment: It's a function call. It goes to the call stack. But please *do not* draw any conclusions from that. Different implementations can treat logging differently. It *might* be asynchronous within some bounds. It should be irrelevant to the end result.

Answer (score 1):

just `console.trace();`, The method outputs a stack trace to the Web console.
@see [MDN: console.trace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/trace)